# For which values $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $u(x,y) = ax^2+2xy+by^2$ is it the real part of a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

> For which values $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $$u(x,y) =
>  ax^2+2xy+by^2$$ is  the real part of a holomorphic function in
>   $\mathbb{C}$.

I think we have to take **Cauchy-Riemann theorem**, but I don't know how to find these two constant from a certain function $f(x,y) = u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$.

Is anyone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\begin{cases}v_x=-u_y=-2x-2by \\ v_y=u_x=2ax+2y\end{cases}$$

Now, integrating $v_x$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x,0)$ and $v_y$ from $(x,0)$ to $(x,y)$ and $v_y$ from $(0,0)$ to $(0,y)$ and $v_x$ from $(0,y)$ to $(x,y)$ we get two expressions for $v(x,y)$ that must be equal. Indeed

$$\begin{cases}v(0,y)-v(0,0)=\int_0^y v_y(0,t)dt=y^2 \\v(x,y)-v(0,y)=\int_0^x v_x(t,y)dt=-x^2-2bxy \\ v(x,0)-v(0,0)=\int_0^x v_x(t,0)dt=-x^2 \\v(x,y)-v(x,0)=\int_0^y v_y(x,t)dt=2axy+y^2\end{cases}$$

That is, $$v(x,y)=v(0,0)+y^2-x^2-2bxy=v(0,0)-x^2+2axy+y^2,$$ which gives us $b=-a.$

Finally, one checks that $u(x,y)=ax^2+2xy-ay^2, v(x,y)=v(0,0)-x^2+2axy+y^2$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and, so, $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Do you use the concept of primitive? Could you explain a bit more the integrating part? Why you do that...

Comment: The idea is to integrate from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ following the edges of the rectangle. Since we assume that $v(x,y)$ exists we get two different expressions that must be equal. For example, if we integrate $v_x$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x,0)$ we get $v(x,0)-v(0,0).$ It is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus. See Newton-Leibniz axiom https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: Where come from the idea to integrating on the edges of the rectangle?

Comment: @mfl Where come from the idea to integrating on the edges of the rectangle? Curviligne integral?

Answer (score 3):

[This Result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108116/every-harmonic-function-is-the-real-part-of-a-holomorphic-function) and [Cauchy Riemann Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) shows that $u(x,y)$ is real part of holomorphic function **iff** $u$ is [harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function).
So,$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ i.e. $b=-a$. **QED**