# Why is every real harmonic function the real part of an holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, harmonic-functions

Why is every real harmonic function the real part of an holomorphic function? Can anyone give me a proof please? Is this always the case or are there certain conditions? I think we need a simply connected domain but I don't know why and how to prove it?

Anyone an idea?

thanks for the help

Kind regards.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hope it's better now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every harmonic function is the real part of a holomorphic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108116/every-harmonic-function-is-the-real-part-of-a-holomorphic-function)

Answer (score 2):

Every real harmonic function is **locally** the real part of a holomorphic function.

In fact, if $g$ is a real harmonic function on an open domain $D$, then for every **open ball** $B \subset D$, there exists a holomorphic function $F$ on $B$ such that $g = \text{Re}(F)$.

To prove this, we'll use two facts:

**Fact 1:** Let $f$ be a real continuous function, defined on the circle $\partial B$ that forms the boundary of the ball $B$. There exists a real function $F$ such that:

- $F$ is continuous on the closed ball $\bar B$.
- There exists a holomorphic function $g$ defined on $B$ such $F = \text{Re}(g)$ on $B$. (Hence $F$ is harmonic on $B$.)
- $F$ is equal to $f$ on $\partial B$.

This is $F$ can be constructed using the Poisson integral formula, as you know.

**Fact 2:** Let $f$ be a real continuous function defined on the boundary circle $\partial B$. Suppose there exist two real functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ defined on $\bar B$ such that

- $F_1$ and $F_2$ are continuous on $\bar B$
- $F_1$ and $F_2$ are harmonic inside $B$.
- $F_1$ and $F_2$ are equal to $f$ on $\partial B$.

Then $F_1$ and $F_2$ must be equal, i.e. $F_1 = F_2$ on $\bar B$.

This is the uniqueness theorem for harmonic functions.

---

Okay, so suppose that $F$ is a real harmonic function on the open domain $D$, and suppose that $B$ is an open ball such that $\bar B \subset D$.

Let $f = F|_{\partial B}$ be the restriction of $F$ to the circle $\partial B$. By fact 1, there exists a function $F'$ that is continuous on $\bar B$, equal to the real part of some holomorphic function on $B$, and equal to $f$ on $\partial B$. This $F'$ is harmonic in $B$.

But $F$ and $F'$ are two functions defined on $\bar B$ that are continuous in $\bar B$, harmonic in $B$ and equal to $f$ on $\partial B$. By fact 2, it must be the case that $F = F'$ on $\bar B$.

Since $F'$ is the real part of some holomorphic function on $B$, and $F = F'$, we find that $F$ is the real part of some holomorphic function on $B$.

[If we now weaken the hypotheses so that $B \subset D$ but $\bar B$ is not necessarily in $D$, then we can apply the same logic to disks of smaller radius. The holomorphic functions we get will patch together by the identity theorem. You can work through this.]

---

Finally, I'll give you an example of a real harmonic function is locally but not globally the real part of a holomorphic function.

Let $D$ be the domain $\mathbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Let $f(z) = \log |z|$. This is a real harmonic function.

We want to say that $f(z)$ is the real part of the holomorphic function $\log z$. But the problem is that $\log z$ is not continuously defined on the whole of $D$, because it has a branch cut! $\log z$ is only continuously defined on local neighbourhoods in $D$. On any open ball, we can pick a branch for $\log z$ such that the branch cut doesn't intersect that open ball; then we can say that $f$ is the real part of that branch of $\log z$. But this doesn't work globally.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: You said it is only locally. Does that mean that the proof given here: "Every harmonic function is the real part of a holomorphic function" is incorrect?

Comment: That other proof relies on being able to construct antiderivatives for holomorphic functions. It works on domains like an open disk, but it doesn't work on domains like a punctured disk. The author does say that the domain he's considering is simply connected - which implies that Cauchy's theorem is applicable, which in turn implies that is method for constructing antiderivatives is valid. Of course, the open balls that I'm considering in my answer are simply connected. So there is no contradiction.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand!